# Run server side script on schedule for hosted asp.net application

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, server-side-scripting

I'm in the process of deploying my first website which is written is ASP.NET. I need to run a server side script at set intervals during the day which updates a database even if there is nobody using the site.

I was led to believe that using Windows task scheduler would be the best option but now I've joined a hosting company the layout is not really how I was expecting. It's a shared hosting with basic FTP and no apparent built in task scheduler.

The hosting company support is not very good and haven't been able to advise how I could do this so hoped to get help here on options before I consider changing company. [The hosting company starts with 1 and ends with 1 :)]

Comment: Have you read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [windows scheduler alternative for an asp.net webform application which is shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965360/windows-scheduler-alternative-for-an-asp-net-webform-application-which-is-shared) on StackOverflow posted by [this. __curious_geek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89556/this-curious-geek):

> You can write a windows service which will call your application url over a given period of time recurrently. Install and run this service from your personal computer or any other computer that you is mostly [almost 24x7] online.
>
> Another way to this is use website uptime checking services. They call your URL at an interval. There are many free and paid services.

From [Windows Shared hosting - custom scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245612/windows-shared-hosting-custom-scheduled-task) on StackOverflow posted by [GvS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11492/gvs)

> [Jeff Atwood has created blog entry on this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/). In short:
>
> - Add an item to the cache
> - Make it expire on your wanted interval
> - Add a trigger to execute when the cache expires
> - Re-add your item in the trigger